# moore-penrose inverse of complex square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we find the moore penrose inverse of a complex square matrix? Can you give me an example?Actually i need a concrete and detailed example. so please help me.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The standard methods for computing the pseudo-inverse are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Construction). They work for both real and complex matrices.

If the square matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ has full rank, then obviously $A^{\dagger}=A^{-1}$. Otherwise, you can use SVD:
$$
A=USV^{*}, \quad A^{\dagger}=VS^{\dagger}U^*,
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are unitary and
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{S} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad \text{$\tilde{S}$ nonsingular diagonal,}
\quad
S^{\dagger}=\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{S}^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For example:

```
A =

   0.4032 + 0.0876i   0.1678 + 0.0390i   0.5425 + 0.5118i
   0.3174 + 0.3352i   0.9784 + 0.4514i  -0.4416 - 1.3188i
   0.4008 - 0.0504i   0.0979 - 0.2558i   0.2983 + 0.7800i
```

SVD by `[U S V] = svd(A)` gives:

```
U =

   0.1255 + 0.2291i  -0.6548 - 0.2332i   0.6638 + 0.0892i
  -0.1338 - 0.8743i  -0.4106 - 0.1032i  -0.1336 + 0.1437i
  -0.0491 + 0.3835i  -0.5726 - 0.0982i  -0.7116 - 0.0807i

S =

   2.0000         0         0
        0    1.0000         0
        0         0         0

V =

  -0.1520 + 0.0000i  -0.6740 + 0.0000i   0.7230 + 0.0000i
  -0.2993 - 0.3682i  -0.5982 - 0.0853i  -0.6206 - 0.1569i
   0.8410 + 0.2111i  -0.4046 + 0.1300i  -0.2005 + 0.1656i
```

The pseudo-inverse $B=A^{\dagger}=VS^{\dagger}U^*$ is hence

```
B =

   0.4318 - 0.1398i   0.2869 - 0.1360i   0.3897 - 0.0370i
   0.3507 - 0.0725i   0.4354 - 0.1329i   0.2877 + 0.0565i
   0.3116 - 0.2626i   0.0042 + 0.2584i   0.2388 - 0.2806i
```

You can verify, that it is indeed the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse by checking that $ABA=A$, $BAB=B$, $(AB)^*=AB$, and $(BA)^*=BA$ hold.

For larger and more "complicated" matrices, although the algorithms for computing SVD are pretty stable, they are unlikely to identify exactly zero singular values. Therefore, you should consider truncating the tiny (say, of the order "$\text{machine precision}\times\text{largest diagonal element of $S$}$") diagonal elements in the matrix $S$ (that is, set them to zero).